# Direct sum of vector sub spaces in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

I am struggling to solve the below question:

$$ \ $$
let $V$ and $W$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^4$: $$ V=\{(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid a+c=0,b+2d=0\} \\[2ex] W=\{(a,b,c,d) \in\Bbb R^4\mid a=2b,c=d\}$$

Need to check whether $\Bbb R^4=V\text{ Direct Sum }W$.

I approached it by taking inverse of system of equations as below:
$$
\begin{cases}
a+c=y_1 \\ 
b+2d=y_2 \\ 
a-2b=y_3 \\
c-d=y_4
\end{cases}
$$

and able to get:
$$
\begin{cases}
a=\frac{4y_1 - 2y_2 - y_3 - 4y_4}{3} \\ 
b=\frac{2y_1 - y_2 - 2y_3 - 24y_4}{3} \\ 
c=\frac{y_1 - 2y_2 - y_3 - 4y_4}{3} \\
d=\frac{-y_1 + 2y_2 + y_3 + y_4}{3}
\end{cases}
$$

However I am not able to represent them as direct sum of two tupples say $v_1$ element of $V$ and $w_1$ element of $W$ where $v_1$ directSum $w_1$

This is not an assignment question.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $$V=span\{\begin{pmatrix}-1\\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\
-2\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}\}=span\{\textbf{v}_1,\textbf{v}_2\}$$
$$W=span\{\begin{pmatrix}2\\
1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\
0\\
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}\}=span\{\textbf{w}_1,\textbf{w}_2\}$$

If every vector form $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ can be written as the linear combination **v**+**w**, where **v** $\in V$ and **w** $\in W$, then we are nearly done.

Let's check it now.

Since there are exactly 4 vectors from $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ above, we may use determinant to check whether those 4 vectors from a basis of $V+W$, span $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ or not  .

As $$ \begin{vmatrix}-1 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & -2 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=3 \neq 0$$, those 4 vectors are linearly independent and span  $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.

It means $$\mathbb{R}^{4}=V+W$$

Now, the last thing we need to make sure is $$V\cap W =\{\textbf{0}\}$$.

Clearly, $\{\textbf{0}\} \subseteq\ V\cap W$ as $V\cap W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.

To show $\{\textbf{0}\} \supseteq\ V\cap W$, picking any vector **x** $\in V\cap W $

$$\textbf{x}=c_1\textbf{v}_1+c_2\textbf{v}_2=d_1\textbf{w}_1+d_2\textbf{w}_2$$
$$\implies \textbf{0}=\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}=c_1\textbf{v}_1+c_2\textbf{v}_2-(d_1\textbf{w}_1+d_2\textbf{w}_2)$$

As these 4 vectors are linearly independent, the equation above has only trivial solution.

It yields the result $c_1=c_2=-d_1=-d_2=0$, so $\textbf{x}=\textbf{0}$.

Now we may conclude that $$V\cap W =\{\textbf{0}\}$$

So the sum $\mathbb{R}^{4}=V+W$ is a direct sum.

i.e. $\mathbb{R}^{4}=V \oplus W$

Comment: Thanks Jade, just one question, since we have proven that the 4 vectors are linearly independent, do we still have to prove $V \cap W = \{0\}$. Would Linearly independence of 4 vectors not imply intersection is zero vector automatically.

Comment: Ya you are right, I'll improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both subspaces are clearly two-dimensional. For $\mathbb R^4$ to be their direct sum, we must have $V\cap W=\{0\}$. Each of these subspaces is defined by a system of two homogeneous linear equations; their intersection is the solution space of the combined system of four equations. How many solutions does this system have?

Comment: The system is invert able and for $y_1=y_2=y_3=y_4=0$ we get $a=b=c=d=0$ because of this I am interpreting $V \cap W = \{(0,0,0,0)\}$. Please correct me if I am wrong.